# C++ passing by reference instead of value

Tags: c++, qt

I have done a lot more C programming than C++, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around references vs pointers.  I'm running into this problem in Qt:

```
class node : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit node(QObject *parent = 0);
     explicit node(QObject *parent = 0, QGraphicsRectItem * obj = Q_NULLPTR);
     explicit node(QObject *parent = 0, QGraphicsRectItem * obj = Q_NULLPTR, int val = 0);
}
private:
    QGraphicsRectItem * rect; 
    int terrain;
```

...

```
node::node(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    terrain = 0;
    rect = Q_NULLPTR;
}

node::node(QObject *parent, QGraphicsRectItem *obj) : QObject(parent)
{
    terrain = 0;
    rect = obj;
}

node::node(QObject *parent, QGraphicsRectItem *obj, int val) : QObject(parent)
{
    terrain = val;
    rect = obj;
}
```

...

```
QObject * root = new QObject();
node * myNode = new node(root);
```

I want to just pass the root pointer to my node constructor but the compiler is complaining that I'm actually passing a reference to a pointer which is ambiguous:

> mainwindow.cpp:26: error: call of overloaded 'node(QObject*&)' is
>   ambiguous
>
> ```
>  node * mynode = new node(root);
> ```

Is there something I'm missing?  The new operator returns a pointer does it not?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo,  It is indeed node * mynode

Comment: What's hidden behind that `Q_OBJECT` macro?

Comment: The point of the error message is "ambiguous", there're more than one candidate constructors.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: I included the other constructors.  The example should be complete now.  The Q_OBJECT macro is part of the Qt framework I'm not really sure what it does specifically but it is required to subclass a QObject.

Comment: You do not need first two constructors. Or remove default argument values.

Comment: @jpsalm According to what you see, I see that the 3rd constructor is only necessary, the first and the second are the special cases of the 3rd. I recommend eliminating the initial 2 constructors and only use the third one.

Comment: @jpsalm 
the compiler do not know which constructor to use that when using: `node * myNode = new node (root);` the 3 constructors are possible options and then the constructor will throw it at random or the one you like the most? :D you must not have equivalent constructors.

Comment: If you still want default values, add them in member initialization list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed your constructor are ambiguous...

let's try to explain you why, with simple function.

```
void f(int i, int j){cout<<i<<endl;}
void f(int i){cout<<i<<endl;}
```

is fine...

BUT:

```
void f(int i, int j = 0){cout<<i<<endl;}
void f(int i){cout<<i<<endl;}
```

Is not fine, as you can call:

```
f(2,3); 
f(2);
```

How the compiler can know which function to use when you called f(2). It could be either:

```
void f(int i, int j = 0){cout<<i<<endl;}
```

or

```
void f(int i){cout<<i<<endl;}
```

default parameter have been invented to avoid to rewrite a function n times...
remove the declaration of:

```
explicit node(QObject *parent = 0);
explicit node(QObject *parent = 0, QGraphicsRectItem * obj = Q_NULLPTR);
```

and everything will be fine :-).

Comment: Thanks David that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: you should change the question to something like:
What does anbiguous call means :-)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid default parameter definitions in constructors if you are overloading it.  The constructors will be ambiguous.  The compiler will not know which function to call as it has default parameters. All the constructors can be called in the same way with single parameter.

```
 explicit node(QObject *parent = 0);
 explicit node(QObject *parent = 0, QGraphicsRectItem * obj = Q_NULLPTR);
 explicit node(QObject *parent = 0, QGraphicsRectItem * obj = Q_NULLPTR, int val = 0);
```

If you are using only one parameter to construct the node object, then it will be like

```
node(parent) ;// first constructor 
node(parent) ;// second constructor 
node(parent) ;// third constructor
```

it will be repetitive as the compiler will not know which one to call at the time of constructing the object.